# What is the next portion of the US government that will be shutdown?

Tags: united-states, congress, budget, government-shutdown, funding

Currently, it appears that around 25% of the US government is shutdown. To the best of my understanding, this is because different departments funding expires at different times. What does the timeline, both in terms of departments and percentage of government by spending, look like going forward as to department shutdowns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congress has passed H.R5895 and H.R6157 with Fiscal Year 2019 (FY19) [appropriations for these departments](https://www.congress.gov/resources/display/content/Appropriations+for+Fiscal+Year+2019). Both bills are signed into law by President Trump.

- Department of Energy (funded by [H.R.5895](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/5895))
- Department of Veterans Affairs (funded by [H.R.5895](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/5895))
- Department of Defense (funded by [H.R.6157](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6157))
- Department of Labor (funded by [H.R.6157](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6157))
- Department of Health and Human Services (funded by [H.R.6157](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6157))
- Department of Education (funded by [H.R.6157](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6157))

The federal government’s fiscal year [begins on October 1 every year](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-does-the-united-states-begin-its-fiscal-year-on-october-1st), per the [Congressional Budget and Impoundment Control Act of 1974](https://history.house.gov/Historical-Highlights/1951-2000/Congressional-Budget-and-Impoundment-Control-Act-of-1974/). Thus, the funding for these departments will expire on September 30, 2019.

For reference, these are the departments currently shut down, due to a lack of appropriations:

- Department of the Treasury
- Department of Agriculture
- Department of Homeland Security
- Department of the Interior
- Department of State
- Department of Housing and Urban Development
- Department of Transportation
- Department of Commerce
- Department of Justice

Comment: Do the departments listed above, and those currently shut down make up the entirety of the federal government than? Or are there any more between now and October that risk not getting funded?

Comment: You say Congress has passed those bills (and imply that they're law, which I believe they are), but it's worth _also_ noting whether or not Trump has signed them.  After all, the current Congress may pass bills which he vetos.

Comment: @spmoose There are some exceptions where agencies are funded directly. Funding for these agencies may expire but are more complicated. However, generally, departments are funded as a whole. See [this answer for an example on NBIB](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/37619/9638) and [this answer for an explanation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37868/is-there-a-list-of-all-or-major-us-federal-expenditures-that-are-funded-speciall).

Comment: @Bobson Good call, I’ve included the note.

Comment: I had actually been about to post a question about which parts of the government *aren't* shut down, because I keep seeing references to a partial shutdown but such-and-such is closed.  Now it makes sense.

Comment: @Bobson There is [a similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37886/why-is-3-4-of-the-us-federal-government-unaffected-by-a-shutdown) asking why 3/4 of the government isn’t affected by the shutdown.

Comment: @Panda This question states that 75% is affected, that similar question states that 75% is not affected. Both cannot be true at the same time.

Comment: @Sjoerd Only 25% of the government is shutdown; it’s probably a typo on the OP’s part.

Comment: @Panda In that case, I've fixed OP's wording.